# Blackberry: how to find subnet mask of connected network

Tags: java, blackberry, wifi, blackberry-jde

How can I find the subnet mask of connected wifi network in Blackberry jde 4.5+ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I believe there is [no reliable way to do this in BlackBerry Java](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-find-subnet-mask/td-p/1413077).

[You can get the Wi-Fi IP address](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/wifi-ip-address/td-p/374272), but not the subnet mask.

I was hoping that maybe you could reverse engineer the subnet mask by attempting a UDP broadcast connection, [but it looks like that's not supported either](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/UDP-sending-and-receiving-problems/m-p/368024/highlight/true#M69260).

Certainly, if you're on a Wi-Fi network where you have access to a web interface for the Wi-Fi router, you could try to *scrape* subnet mask values off the router.  But, that's only likely to be useful for your home network, and I assume you'd like this code to work anywhere.

So, I don't think there's a good solution :(

Comment: Thank you @Nate, Yes I think that I would have to skip subnet calculation from my list :(